# Migration from google maps V2 to Version 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a migration project from google maps V2 to V3 and can't get the following working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApiKey&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"));
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),5);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually I don't want to use the options parameter in the new `google.maps.Map` function. I want to center the map using map.center function.

Comment: what seems to be the problem/error?

Comment: why are you using an API key? I thought it was not needed anymore...

Comment: and the problem is...

Comment: Map is not loading .Only a light grey shaded area.When I checked the error console I couldnt find anything relavant

Comment: Still I couldnt find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),5);
```

setCenter only takes one parameter, the LatLng object.  Try this:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850));
```